# Optimising Jquery Code

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using a jquery smart wizard script to make my forms into wizards.

This works very well, but the validation code looks like it could be made simpler.

This is the example they provide. Could this be made into a loop so I don't have to write it for each of my 5 steps ?

```
function validateSteps(step){
  var isStepValid = true;
   if(step == 1){
    if(validateStep1() == false ){
      isStepValid = false; 
      $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please correct the errors in step '+step+ ' and click next.');
      $('#wizard').smartWizard('setError',{stepnum:step,iserror:true});         
    }else{
      $('#wizard').smartWizard('hideMessage');
      $('#wizard').smartWizard('setError',{stepnum:step,iserror:false});
    }
}

    if(step == 3){
     if(validateStep3() == false ){
       isStepValid = false; 
       $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please correct the errors in step '+step+ ' and click next.');
       $('#wizard').smartWizard('setError',{stepnum:step,iserror:true});         
     }else{
       $('#wizard').smartWizard('hideMessage');
       $('#wizard').smartWizard('setError',{stepnum:step,iserror:false});
     }
    }

    return isStepValid;
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Well you need to post these kinda questions **[here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)**

Comment: For optimizing you need to show how `validateStep1()` and `validateStep2()` , ..... so on, looks like! so can generalize it.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Sad to say it but, *"This is the example they provide."* indicates that the OP did not write this code himself which makes it off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: I agree @SimonAndréForsberg. Well he can remove it though!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this,

```
function validateSteps(){
        var isStepValid = true, step =1;
        for(step ;step <=5;step ++){
            if(window["validateStep"+step ]() == false ){
              isStepValid = false; 
              $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please correct the errors in step '+step + ' and click next.');
              $('#wizard').smartWizard('setError',{stepnum:step ,iserror:true});         
            }else{
              $('#wizard').smartWizard('hideMessage');
              $('#wizard').smartWizard('setError',{stepnum:step ,iserror:false});
            }

        }
        return isStepValid;

    }
```

You just have to worry about having a function named validateStepX

Comment: Thanks that seems to help